# Section 5.1 of Wald's *General Relativity*

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

I have been reading section[5.1] 'Homogeneity and Isotropy' from *General Relativity* by Robert M. Wald. If you look in the 1984-edition of the book (PDF is available) it is on pages 91-92.

> "We shall now show that the second requirement implied by isotropy is particularly restrictive. Consider the  Riemann tensor  $^{(3)}{R_{abc}}^d$ constructed from $h_{ab}$ on $\Sigma_t$. If we raise the third index with $h^{ab}$, we may view $^{(3)}{R_{ab}}^{cd}$ at point $p$ as a linear map, $L$, of the vector space $W$ of two-forms [i.e., antisymmetric tensors of rank $(0,2)$] at $p$ into itself $L:W\to W$. By equation (3.2.20), $L$ is symmetric, i.e., it is a self-adjoint map (with the natural, positive definite inner product on $W$ determined by $h_{ab}$). Therefore, $W$ has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors of $L$. If the eigenvalues of these eigen­vectors were distinct, then we would be able to give a geometrical prescription for picking out a preferred two-form at $p$ and, consequently, a preferred vector at $p$. Hence, in order not to violate isotropy, all the eigenvalues of $L$ must be equal. This means that $L$ is a multiple of the identity operator $L= K I$."

I am a novice and I have not understood which tensor can be assumed as 'antisymmetric tensors of rank $(0,2)$'?  And also the line - 'we may view $^{(3)}{R_{ab}}^{cd}$ at point $p$ as a linear map .... $W$ determined by $h_{ab}$).'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tensor is said to be antisymmetric if exchanging two indices flips its sign. In the particular case of rank $(0,2)$ tensors, this means simply $F_{ab} = - F_{ba}$. Furthermore, notice that ${}^{(3)}R_{ab}{}^{cd} = - {}^{(3)}R_{ba}{}^{cd} = {}^{(3)}R_{ba}{}^{dc}$ (i.e., is is antisymmetric in the upper and in the lower indices). Hence, the tensor $F'_{ab}$ defined by $F'_{ab} = {}^{(3)}R_{ab}{}^{cd} F_{cd}$ is also antisymmetric and of rank $(0,2)$. In this sense, ${}^{(3)}R_{ab}{}^{cd}$ maps antisymmetric tensors of rank $(0,2)$ into antisymmetric tensors of rank $(0,2)$.

As for the inner product induced by $h_{ab}$, it is just the index contraction with respect to $h_{ab}$. More specifically, $\langle F_{ab} | G_{cd} \rangle = F_{ab}G_{cd}h^{ac}h^{bd}$. With respect to this inner product, the map defined by ${}^{(3)}R_{ab}{}^{cd}$ is self-adjoint. In Quantum Mechanics, we usually use the word "Hermitian", which might be more familiar, despite there being a few technical differences.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer.