# Section 5.1 of Wald's *General Relativity* - part II

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature

I am asking this in continuation of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/681811/).

From the answer of that link and from section[5.1] of 'Homogeneity and Isotropy' from General Relativity by Robert M. Wald (pages 91-92, edition 1984) whatever I have understood is that -

$\Sigma_t$ is a spacelike hypersurface for some fixed time $t$. The hypersurface is homogeneous.

The metric of whole space is $g$ and the form of the metric on hypersurface $\Sigma_t$ is $h$. Thus if $g$ is the metric of dimension $4$, then $\Sigma_t$ has dimension $3$. Next, Riemann curvature tensor $R_{ab}{}^{cd}$ is defined from the metric $h$ (Or, from the metric $g$, I am not sure about this). Now, if there is an antisymmetric tensor $A_{ij}$ defined on $\Sigma_t$, this tensor is transformed by $R_{ab}{}^{cd}$ as $A'_{ij} \to R_{ij}{}^{cd}A_{cd}$. $R_{ij}{}^{cd}$ itself is antisymmetric with respect to its two indices $i$ and $j$. This transformation can be viewed as linear self-adjoint transformation. If we name this linear transformation as $L$ and vector space as $W$, then $L: W\to W$. This vector space $W$ can be spanned by eigenvector $L$. The corresponding eigenvalues must be equal because of isotropy. Thus $L$ can be expressed as multiple of the identity operator i.e. $L=K I$.

Then he suddenly claimed that $$R_{ab}{}^{cd} = K\delta^c{}_{[a} \delta^d{}_{b]}.$$

I have not understood how to claim this equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is essentially writing $L = KI$ in index notation. Let us pick some $A_{ij} \in W$. Then notice how
\begin{align}
A'_{ij} &\equiv \delta^k{}_{[i}\delta^l{}_{j]}A_{kl}, \\
&= \delta^k{}_{[i}A_{kl}\delta^l{}_{j]}, \\
&= A_{[i|l|}\delta^l{}_{j]}, \\
&= A_{[ij]}, \\
&= A_{ij},
\end{align}
where I used indices $i,j,k,l$ to make it clear that this calculation is taking place on the three-dimensional manifold $\Sigma_t$, not on the entire spacetime, but I'll go back to Wald's convention ($a,b,c,d$) now. The calculation above means that just as ${}^{(3)}R_{ab}{}^{cd}$ can be seen as a map $L : W \to W$, $\delta^c{}_{[a}\delta^d{}_{b]}$ is just the index-notation expression of the identity map $I : W \to W$.

As for whether $R_{ab}{}^{cd}$ is build out of $g$ or $h$, notice that $R_{ab}{}^{cd}$ is defined in terms of $g$, but ${}^{(3)}R_{ab}{}^{cd}$ is defined with $h$. Wald's Eq. (5.12) is ${}^{(3)}R_{ab}{}^{cd} = K \delta^c{}_{[a}\delta^d{}_{b]}$, *not* $R_{ab}{}^{cd} = K \delta^c{}_{[a}\delta^d{}_{b]}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: @PoreyS You are welcome! If the answer solves you question, please consider [accepting it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)